# Spring Data Neo4j SDN 6 do something after a record was created

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

How can I do smth. after a record was created (not updated)? The only callbacks I found are `AfterConvertCallback` and `BeforeBindCallback`. However the former is not called for new records the latter is called before the record is persisted. I use the standard `Neo4jRepository.save()` method.

Whenever a new record of a specific type is added to the DB I have to check if it is related to existing ones. Therefore, one can implement an interface that gets the newly created node and do some custom logic to relate it to existing nodes. Think of it like components that can determine who knows who and there are matchers for byFreetimeActivity, byWork, etc. As these computations may take some time I do not want to do it before persisting. Simply relating them by a custom query like `MATCH (person1:Person)-[:WORKED_ON]-()<-[:WORKED_ON]-(person2) CREATE UNIQUE (person1)-[:KNOWS]-(person2)` is not sufficient I believe as business logic is involved like: did they work at the same company in an overlapping period.

Comment: What is the exact use-case? What do you want to perform?

Comment: Whenever a new record of a specific type is added to the DB I have to check if it is related to existing ones. Therefore, one can implement an interface that gets the newly created node and do some custom logic to relate it to existing nodes. Think of it like components that can determine who knows who and there are matchers for byFreetimeActivity, byWork, etc. As these computations may take some time I do not want to do it before persisting.

Comment: You can write a custom query for that.

Comment: How? it's not like it's just a path that has to exist. It's business logic like: did they work at the same company in an overlapping period.

Comment: Can you update the exact requirements in the question?

Comment: Added more info

Comment: You can add your business logic after the `save` method call, in your service or dao layer and then take actions on the basis of that. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: As I want to perform it only for new records I would have to check that and have to make sure that it is done for each case where a record of that type is created. Thought there might be a more elegant way using some sort of callback or event. But yes this would be possible.

Comment: Yeah, I believe that's the only way right now.